Best use of a steam engine for blacksmithing in a medieval society?
Writing a fantasy novel where the MC has managed to create a steam engine in a medieval society. What role could it play to increase the efficiency of forging weapons or smelting ores? As in, a steam-powered hammer for moulding weapons and such.

It would help you to understand our requirements and standards if you were to finish the [tour] and read the [ask] section of the [help]. The question as written needs more clarity and focus. What's the specific problem to solve here, what have you considered and why have you discarded it? Remember fishing for ideas is off-topic here.

If you look at history, the best option would be to pump water out of mines and pump fresh air in That is an application where steam is better than water power.
If you have a single engineer in a mostly-medieval world, consider to use steam power for forced draft. This might allow one character to work as a smith, without hordes of apprentices to complicate the setting. You could go as far as inventing a steam-powered blast furnace.

I've already written about a steam pump but that draft idea and the steam furnace is interesting. I'll need to look that up more, thanks.

@CurrySpicy, yes, but I wanted to point out that this is where water power is no alternative. Your smith would have colleagues/competitors who use water for any other thing he does with steam, unless there is no water power (but then how to get feedwater?).

@o.m. Hydropower needs running water, steam power doesn't. The water could come from a well (perhaps steam-driven?) or the sea, or from a low-lying, slow-flowing river that isn't fast enough to provide power for smithing.

Smithies run on heat, steam engines convert heat to mechanical energy. You could run your whole smithy from it. Hammers, shapers, blowers etc,. and become very efficient.
The differences between manual hammering and having a machine do the work are huge. If you have time look up the Indian blacksmiths mass-producing tools and parts on one or two heatings. Whereas manual hammering is a slow process and for anything large or complex you have to reheat more often.

Industrial quantities of Material
So, a traditional blacksmith is limited (to a degree) by the amount of Metal they can lift and work with at any given time.
I have not done any black smithing, but I imagine that once you get over a few Kilos of Material, it becomes increasingly hard to work with.
Having a Steam Powered shop crane or having Steam powered Ladels to pour into multiple Molds is probably the best usage - because now you are going form working with Kilos of Metal to tonnes of metal - and that is going to be your biggest driver in efficiency.
